# Sublime Text 3 Markdown block comment

Tags: comments, sublimetext3, markdown

Let's say I have this text with **pipes** marking selection:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut |labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit| esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

If I hit my **toggle comment** hotkey, I get this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut <!-- labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit --> esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

But I want this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
<!-- tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, -->
<!-- quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo -->
<!-- consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse -->
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

How can I get this?

---

**EDIT:** I also want to be able to remove the comments quickly, basically I want them to work exactly as line comments in C.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting code works either per selection or per line. You can select all three lines, then use the “split into lines” command and then toggle comments.

The same works for multi-selections, but in your case that's less applicable.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I get the comments this way, but I would also be able to remove them the same way.

Comment: Basically I want them to work the same way as line comments in C, but I guess I won't get that